# How to change frame on button event Java

Tags: java

I am making a simple project. It has login window like this[image]

When the user click on button log in - it should "repaint" the window(it should seem to be happened in the same window) and then  the window looks like this.
[image]

The problem is - I can't "repaint" the window - the only thing I can - it's create a new frame, so there actually are 2 frames totally.
How to make the whole thing in one same frame.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Client
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea allMessagesArea;
    private JTextArea inputArea;
    private JButton buttonSend;
    private JButton buttonExit;
    private String login;

    public  void addComponentsToPane(Container pane)
    {
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        allMessagesArea = new JTextArea(25,50);
        c.weighty = 0.6;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        c.gridwidth=2;
        pane.add(allMessagesArea, c);


        inputArea = new JTextArea(12,50);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridwidth=2;
        c.weighty =0.3;
        c.gridx =0;
        c.gridy =1;
        pane.add(inputArea, c);

        buttonSend = new JButton("Send");
        c.weightx=0.5;
        c.weighty = 0.1;
        c.fill =  GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx =0;
        c.gridy=2;
        c.gridwidth =1;
        pane.add(buttonSend, c);


        buttonExit = new JButton("Exit");
        c.weightx =0.5;
        c.weighty = 0.1;
        c.fill =  GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx =1;
        c.gridy=2;
        c.gridwidth =1;
        pane.add(buttonExit, c);
    }


    public Client()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Simple Client");

        frame.setSize(400,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        welcomePage();



        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void welcomePage()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Your login:");
        panel.add(label);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
        panel.add(textField);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("log in");
        panel.add(loginButton);

        JButton exitButton = new JButton("exit");
        panel.add(exitButton);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(textField.getText().isEmpty())
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame.getContentPane(), "Please enter your login");
                else
                {
                    login = textField.getText();
                    System.out.println(login);
                    frame = null;
                    frame = new JFrame("Simple Client");
                    frame.setSize(400,500);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                }
            }
        });

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Client frame = new Client();
    }
}
```

Comment: Some ideas for you: 1) You can have the log in and the info panel in one frame. Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html. Or better yet, do a search on ./here about multi layered JFrame/JPanel to see how other people approach this. So that will basically get all your panels in one Jframe. 2) With that out of the way, the only thing left to do is to do some manoeuvre about which Jpanel to display or on top of another. I think that should be enough to keep you going.

Comment: Alternatively, can you divide your JFrame into two part: top and bottom where the top shows the login and the bottom shows the info. This depends on the flow of your application. Perhaps have a read about this too.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. First approach is more "elegant". I will try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One of the solutions

You can create two panels (one for each view) and add the required components to them. First, you add first panel to the `frame` (using `frame.add(panel1)`). If you want to show the second panel in the same window, you can delete first panel (using `frame.remove(panel1)`) and add the second panel (using `frame.add(panel2)`). At the end you've to call `frame.pack()`.

This's your code with above solution:

```
public class Client
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea allMessagesArea;
    private JTextArea inputArea;
    private JButton buttonSend;
    private JButton buttonExit;
    private String login;

    public  void addComponentsToPanel2()
    {               
        panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        allMessagesArea = new JTextArea(25,50);
        c.weighty = 0.6;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        c.gridwidth=2;
        panel2.add(allMessagesArea, c);


        inputArea = new JTextArea(12,50);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridwidth=2;
        c.weighty =0.3;
        c.gridx =0;
        c.gridy =1;
        panel2.add(inputArea, c);

        buttonSend = new JButton("Send");
        c.weightx=0.5;
        c.weighty = 0.1;
        c.fill =  GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx =0;
        c.gridy=2;
        c.gridwidth =1;
        panel2.add(buttonSend, c);


        buttonExit = new JButton("Exit");
        c.weightx =0.5;
        c.weighty = 0.1;
        c.fill =  GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx =1;
        c.gridy=2;
        c.gridwidth =1;
        panel2.add(buttonExit, c);   
    }


    public Client()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Simple Client");

        frame.setSize(400,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        welcomePage();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void welcomePage()
    {
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Your login:");
        panel1.add(label);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
        panel1.add(textField);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("log in");
        panel1.add(loginButton);

        JButton exitButton = new JButton("exit");
        panel1.add(exitButton);
        frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(textField.getText().isEmpty())
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame.getContentPane(), "Please enter your login");
                else
                {
                    login = textField.getText();
                    System.out.println(login);

                    panel2 = new JPanel();
                    addComponentsToPanel2();
                    frame.remove(panel1);
                    frame.add(panel2);
                    //frame.repaint();
                    frame.pack();
                }
            }
        });

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Client frame = new Client();
    }

    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
}
```

Comment: Instead of removing the currently displayed panel in order to display another one, just use `CardLayout`

Answer (score 3):

[Use `CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

This layout allows developers to switch between panels. It works by creating a "deck" panel that'll contain all of panels that'll potentially be displayed:

```
CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
JPanel deck = new JPanel();
deck.setLayout(layout);

JPanel firstCard = new JPanel();
JPanel secondCard = new JPanel();
deck.add(firstCard, "first");
deck.add(secondCard, "second");
```

When you click on a button, that button's `ActionListener` should call `show(Container, String)`, `next(Container)` or `previous(Container)` on the `CardLayout` to switch which panel is being displayed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    layout.show(deck, "second");
}
```